# Why can't I query Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Connections?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, lambda, interop

The Connections object is a IEnumerable per:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.connections.aspx

I just want to remove the commented line with a lambda expression in the foreach

this:

```
    foreach (WorkbookConnection connection in book.Connections)
    {
        if (connection.Type != XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB) continue;
        var conString = connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection.ToString();
        if (conString.Contains("Initial Catalog") && conString.Contains("Data Source"))
            connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = conString.Replace(ExlCubeServer,
                Settings.Default.OLAPServer[1]);
    }
```

to something like:

```
    foreach (WorkbookConnection connection in book.Connections.Cast<Connections>().Where(c => c.Type == XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB))
    {
        //if (connection.Type != XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB) continue;
        var conString = connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection.ToString();
        if (conString.Contains("Initial Catalog") && conString.Contains("Data Source"))
            connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = conString.Replace(ExlCubeServer,
                Settings.Default.OLAPServer[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just casting the book.Connections to a WorkBookConnection rather than a Connection?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Are you getting compile error or runtime exception, where and what type? Is the posted code what you really use? Because `book.Connections.Cast<Connections>()` is definitely wrong, it should be `book.Connections.Cast<WorkbookConnection>()`.

Comment: @DanAndrews The generic type argument of the  `Cast<T>` is the type of the collection **element**, not the type of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I query Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Connections?

You are misinterpreting the [Enumerable.Cast<TResult>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)  generic type argument.

According to the documentation:

> *Syntax:*
>
> public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
>
> *Return Value:*
>
> An IEnumerable<T> that contains each **element** of the source sequence **cast** to the **specified type**.

Shortly, `TResult` is the type of the collection **element** and not the type of the collection as you are trying to use it.

So changing `.Cast<Connections>()` to `.Cast<WorkbookConnection>()` will fix the problem:

```
foreach (var connection in book.Connections.Cast<WorkbookConnection>()
    .Where(c => c.Type == XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB))
{
    var conString = connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection.ToString();
    if (conString.Contains("Initial Catalog") && conString.Contains("Data Source"))
        connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = conString.Replace(ExlCubeServer,
            Settings.Default.OLAPServer[1]);
}
```

P.S. I'm wondering what has stopped you to resolve the issue at the first place.

When I bring the code from your sample in VS

```
Workbook book = null;
foreach (WorkbookConnection connection in book.Connections.Cast<Connections>().Where(c => c.Type == XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB))
{
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error pointing to `c.Type`

> Error  CS1061: 'Connections' does not contain a definition for 'Type' and no extension method 'Type' accepting a first argument of type 'Connections' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

which clearly indicates that `c` is not what you are expecting, and indeed hovering it with the mouse shows that `c` is of type `Connections`.

Answer (score 1):

```
book.Connections.ToList().Where(c => c.Type == XlConnectionType.xlConnectionTypeOLEDB).ToList().ForEach(connection => PerformAction(connection));

public static void PerformAction(WorkbookConnection connection)
{
    var conString = connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection.ToString();

    if (conString.Contains("Initial Catalog") && conString.Contains("Data Source"))
        connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = conString.Replace(ExlCubeServer,
            Settings.Default.OLAPServer[1]);
}
```

Comment: Your code will work, but it doesn't answer the question, why can't we query the collection which is a IEnumerable?